# How to fix WindowSoftInputMode and WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus incompatibility?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm writing an XF app. Setting

`WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize`

together with

`Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);`

doesn't work.

everyone suggests to set

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

but I don't know where to put it in Android project. Suggestions?

Btw, I'm not using any xml in my xamarin.android project.

Here's how my MainActivity looks like:

```
[Activity(Label = "App", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
public class MainActivity : FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` inside the xml.

Comment: i'm not using any xml in my xamarin.android project